# Typescript error when trying to prevent default behavior with DataGrid onRowEditStop

Tags: typescript, material-ui, datagrid

this is my first time posting a question...
I have a small error when trying to prevent the default behavior of the key "Enter" on the method "onRowEditStop" of the DataGrid component.

this is my code :

```
<DataGrid
    rows={sites?.map((site) => ({ ...site, setSites })) || []}
    processRowUpdate={tryCatchWrapper(updateSite)}
    // this is the line that is bothering
    onRowEditStop={(_, e) => e.key === "Enter" && (e.defaultMuiPrevented = true)} // FIX ME
    columns={columns}
    loading={isLoading}
    editMode="row"
    sx={dataGridStyles[0]}
    disableSelectionOnClick
    experimentalFeatures={{ newEditingApi: true }}
    pageSize={10}
    rowsPerPageOptions={[10]}
  />
```

The code actually works but eslint keeps displaying this error

> Property 'key' does not exist on type 'MuiEvent'.
> Property 'key' does not exist on type '{ defaultMuiPrevented?: boolean | undefined; }'.

I've tried a bunch of stuff but since i just started learning typescript i dont want to give up on the answer.

Comment: Have you tried React.KeyboardEvent as type for event? You'd have to explore the different types inside DataGrid component to select the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

```
onRowEditStop={(_, e) => {
      const { key } = e as KeyboardEvent;
      if (key && key === "Enter") e.defaultMuiPrevented = true;
    }}
```

At the end i solved it this way !